# WooCommerce product custom discounted price for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, discount

I have a question about managing prices in WooCommerce.

I have a store only with simple products. Let's say that for all subscribers and customers the regular price of each product is discounted by 10%. This was easy:

```
    function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price');
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return $price = ($price * 0.9);
        } else{
            return $price;      
        }
   }
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2);
```

For products that already have a sale price, I would like woocommerce to calculate the discount for logged in users on the regular price, and that the customer could see the lowest price between the sale price and the discounted price. Therefore:

Scenario 1

- Regular price: 100
- Price dedicated to logged in users: 90 (10% off on regular price)
- Product sale price: 85
- The price for logged in user must be: 85

Scenario 2

- Regular price: 100
- Price dedicated to logged in users: 90 (10% off on regular price)
- Product sale price: 95
- The price for logged in user must be: 90

Woocommerce, with the snippet above, instead calculates the 10% discount for logged in users on the sale price, returning:

Scenario 1

- product price for logged in users: 76.5 (10% off on the sale price, 85)

Scenario 2

- product price for logged in users: 85.5 (10% off on the sale price, 95)

How can I solve it? Thanks for your help

Comment: As a new user, you should take the [visual quick tour (1mn)](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that will show you visually how thinks work basically in StackOverFlow…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question code is outdated and deprecated since WooCommerce 3… Instead use the following that should match your scenario:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_discount_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_discount_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_discount_price( $price, $product ) {
    // For logged in users
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $discount_rate = 0.9; // 10% of discount
        
        // Product is on sale
        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) { 
            // return the smallest price value between on sale price and custom discounted price
            return min( $price, ( $product->get_regular_price() * $discount_rate ) );
        }
        // Product is not on sale
        else {
            // Returns the custom discounted price
            return $price * $discount_rate;
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it runs well.
And what about the sale badge? What can I do so that the percentage discount indicated in the sale badge also follows the same conditional logic? Currently, considering the first scenario, the percentage discount shown in the badgeis 5%, which is correct for users not logged in but wrong for those logged in.

Thank you very much again

Comment: As a new user, you should [take the visual quick tour (1mn)](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that will show you visually how thinks work basically in StackOverFlow… and maybe read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you this works great but only adjusts the price for simple products, how can you make this also adjust the price for a variable product too?